# Use of Overridden functions in a base class array

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, overriding

I am currently having a problem with a concept involving inheritance and arrays of derived objects. I created a pointer array and populated it either with a base class or a derived class depending on if the array position is even or odd. However, When I call the birdType function,all of the objects in the array use the base class  function, even though the even number array objects should be using the overridden version function. I tried to use virtual call mechanism on the base function, but that seems crashes the program.

The code in question:

```
 class bird{
public:
    void birdType(){cout<<"I am a bird.\n";}
};
class sparrow:public bird 
{
    void birdType() { cout <<"I am a sparrow.\n";}
};

int main(){
    bird *collection[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        if (i % 2 != 0) 
        {
            collection[i] = new bird;

        }
        else if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            collection[i] = new sparrow;
        }



    }
    for(int j=0;j<5;++j)collection[j]->birdType();;
}
```

and the current Output:

```
I am a bird
I am a bird
I am a bird
I am a bird
I am a bird
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the `birdType()` function in your base class (bird) virtual. If it isn't virtual, you won't get the inheritance you desire.

```
virtual void birdType(){cout<<"I am a bird.\n";}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: hey thanks for the speedy reply, i must have done something different when I rewrote this, because virtual seems to work now. beforehand my program would crash with virtual on the base function.

Comment: @LOUDNOODLES Glad to hear it! Mind accepting this as the answer, then?